# datatable.net in Angular not recognize the tr inside the table

Tags: javascript, angular, datatable, angular-datatables

this is my problem, sometimes the component render the table like this.

(No problems):

[image]

(Problem):

[image]

In the 2 photo you can see the empty row generated by datatables, it means the datatable not recognize the rows and this implies the datatable options like search or pageLength dont work. What i should do?

This is my table component:

- Template:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="table table-hover" [ngClass]="extraClass" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th *ngFor="let column of columns">{{ column }}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot *ngIf="footer">
            <tr>
                <th *ngFor="let column of columns">{{ column }}</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <ng-content></ng-content>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

- Component:

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { datatableLanguage } from "../../data/index";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html'
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input()
  public columns: Array<string>;

  @Input()
  public extraClass: string;

  @Input()
  public footer: boolean;

  public dtOptions: DataTables.Settings;

  constructor() {
    
    this.columns = new Array<string>(0);
    this.extraClass = '';
    this.footer = true;
    this.dtOptions = {};
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.checkRequiredFields();
    
    this.dtOptions = {
      "language": datatableLanguage,
      "responsive": true
    }
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.checkRequiredFields();
  }

  checkRequiredFields(): void {
    if(this.columns.length <= 0)
      throw new Error("Attribute 'columns' is required.");
  }
}
```

And if you need it, the father component:

- Table template part:

```
<app-table id="ingredientsTable" [columns]="['Nombre', 'Precio/Unidad', 'Cantidad', 'Acciones']" [footer]="ingredients.length >= 10">
    <tr [class.table-danger]="ingredient.amount <= 0" *ngFor="let ingredient of ingredients">
        <td class="align-middle">{{ ingredient.name }}</td>
        <td class="align-middle text-center">{{ ingredient.priceByUnit | number }}</td>
        <td class="align-middle text-center">{{ ingredient.amount | number }}</td>
        <td>
            <div class="text-center">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-info" (click)="changeModal(ingredient)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalIngredients">
                        <i class="far fa-edit"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteIngredient(ingredient)">
                        <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</app-table>
```

Comment: Do you use angular datatable that in this link https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started

Comment: @JanithaRasanga yeah, i use datatables.net whit bootstrap responsive styles.

Comment: Don't use datatables.net version. Use datatables that I mention in above. Because it is configure for specially to angular. Your case is happen because datatable is don't trigger after binding the data to table. Check this link to get idea. https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/angular-way  (for trigger the table)

Comment: @JanithaRasanga, i think is the same npm package, because of package.json don't change, but i see the link, in the example they use a subject to render the table after the get data, but my table is in another component and the content is in the father, how can i do that?

Comment: I have no idea for that. Try to get those code to one component

Comment: @JanithaRasanga, Ok thanks for your help, but i need the component in different parts of my app then i can't do that.